# Symbolic integration of Exponential

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

How can I solve this integration? I want to solve this integration with `c, B, H, Y, b, w` surviving as constants in the result:

```
ClearAll[a, b, t, R1, R2 c, t, H, Y, w]
syms = {c, B, H, Y, b, w}
a = Exp[((t)^(c) - 1)]

R1 = Integrate[a^(-3*w - 3), t]
```

Second question

```
a = Exp[(1/\[Beta]) *((t^\[Beta]) - 1)];
R1 = a*(2/(3*w))*
  Exp[(2/(3*w))*Integrate[Exp[-m*t^k], t] /. {m -> 3*(w + 1)/\[Beta], 
     k -> \[Beta]}]

f = D[R1, t]

p1 = Plot[f /. {\[Beta] -> .58, w -> -1.1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code.  Mathematica can't do the integral.  However, it can do it for specific integer values of `c`.  Does that help?

Answer (score 5):

It is necessary to use the well-known integral

```
Integrate[Exp[-m*t^k], t]

(*Out[]= -((t (m t^k)^(-1/k) Gamma[1/k, m t^k])/k)*)
```

Let's transform

```
a = Exp[((t)^(c) - 1)];(* a^(-3*w - 3)=Exp[3*w+3]*Exp[-3*(w+1)*t^c]*);
```

Consequently

```
R1=Exp[3 + 3*w]*Integrate[Exp[-m*t^k], t] /. {m -> 3*(w + 1), k -> c}
(*Out[]= -((3^(-1/c) E^(3 + 3 w) t (t^c (1 + w))^(-1/c)
   Gamma[1/c, 3 t^c (1 + w)])/c)*)
```

Let's check that the derivative `D[R1,t]`coincides with the original function.

```
R1 = -((3^(-1/c) E^(3 + 3 w) t (t^c (1 + w))^(-1/c) Gamma[1/c, 
        3 t^c (1 + w)])/c);
f = D[R1, t]
(*Out[]=E^(3 + 3 w - 3 t^c (1 + w)) + (
 3^(-1/c) E^(3 + 3 w) t^c (1 + w) (t^c (1 + w))^(-1 - 1/c)
   Gamma[1/c, 3 t^c (1 + w)])/c - (
 3^(-1/c) E^(3 + 3 w) (t^c (1 + w))^(-1/c) Gamma[1/c, 3 t^c (1 + w)])/
 c*)
{p1 = Plot[f /. {c -> .58, w -> -1.1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 p2 = Plot[a^(-3*w - 3) /. {c -> .58, w -> -1.1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], Show[p1, p2]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: thank you, how can ı get the differentiation of R1 with m, c surviving as constants in the result

Comment: @merve Do you want to calculate the derivative `D[R1,c]`?

Comment: not actually D[R1,c], I want to calculate D[R1,t] and then plot R1 versus t (with the range of 0-10). with c= 0.58, w = -1.1 values but I couldn't.

Comment: I updated the code added pictures

Comment: thanks a lot. I have another question that I have updated up when I change the parameters why I couldn't plot again. I don't understand.

Comment: This is due to the fact that the function `f[t]` is complex, so use `p1 = Plot[Re[f /. {\[Beta] -> .58, w -> -1.1}], {t, 0, 10},  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: how can I get the values of p1 plot as a text that I can use on the another plot program?